# Android: Activity content (Button) not showing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a button to layout. Button is not showing on device screen, I get a blank screen. Adding a screenshot of Android Studio layout.

[image: Layout]

This is my activity_main.xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is the code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    menu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please width set to "match_parent" not set fixed.

Comment: in you'r question you say "Button is not showing on device screen" but in image there is a button . i tested you'r code in my emulator and button is show. please say more about problem

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you show your `onCreate()`, or anywhere where you define layouts? Also, is this your final Layout? Are there any other `View`s on it? It looks like a hierarchy issue (parent is not who you think it is).

Comment: @SINA Image shows Android Studio layout.

Comment: @Bonatti Added code.

Comment: None of those "codes" are the ones inflating the xml into the activity. You should look for a line such as `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` most likely in your `onCreate()` method, of your `MainActivity` lifecycle....  Post everything. The source Activity, the inflator used, the xmls involved etc. Do not make us get to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never calling `setContentView` to tell it to use your layout:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

So you're getting a blank activity with no content.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in on Create inside mainActivity class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```